# Why does list become None object when I call some attribute in creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 2].sort()
print(a)
```

When I run it on python 3.5, I get a None in output. Why?
Other attributes also return None:

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 2].remove(1)
print(a)
```

Comment: `sort()` is a method. Try `a = sorted([1, 3, 4, 2])`

Comment: @wencakisa Terrible idea with Python 3.

Comment: I guess that `a` is assigned as the return value of `[1, 3, 4, 2].remove(1)`, and both `remove()` and `sort()` return None. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

sort is applied to the list it's a procedure not a function. so 'a' is sorted now

Comment: Except that the now sorted list is no longer `a`, because he reassigned the name `a` to the return value `None`.